# inline-block doesn't prevent menu elements from overlapping when minimizing browser

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have created a menu that each link in it has the same ID #menuu and the class .menu-item. I haven't written any HTML because it was created with a live page builder.

I have the following CSS:

```
#menuu { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #0B1B70; 
} 

.menu-item-text {
    -webkit-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-moz-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
-o-transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
transition: border 200ms ease-out; 
border-bottom: 2.11 pxpx solid transparent; 
border-top: 2.11 pxpx solid transparent; 
padding: 0px; 
height: 35px 
}


#menuu:hover .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:focus .menu-item-text, 
#menuu:active .menu-item-text{ 
border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff; 
}

.active { border-bottom: 2.11px solid #61f6ff !important; 
border-top: 2.11px solid #61f6ff !important; }

#menuu
{
min-width: 60pxpx;
max-width: 235.97px;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 5%;
padding right: 5%;
white-space: nowrap;
position: inline-block
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}
```

I want to prevent the menu items from overlapping each other when minimizing the browser's width. Right now they all go to the center of the page, covering each other. You can inspect it here: [mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il). Display:inline block isn't working for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: `each link in it has the same ID #menuu ` ?? Never use duplicate IDs ! Can you please share the HTML also ? so you create a working example ?

Comment: Hi Mihai, I haven't created HTML because I used a live website builder called Elementor for wordpress. I shared a link above. Thanks for willing to help.

Comment: Inspect element -> copy HTML of the menu -> paste it here :)

Comment: Try removing `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IuFDQcj.png

Comment: ...and remove all the set widths.

Comment: Hi, thanks. White-space is preventing the lines from breaking (which is something I wanna achieve when minimizing the browser). As for the ID's and Classes, I know it's not good to use it but I needed it for some jQuery I have used (the borders animation).

Comment: there is always a solution that doesn't involve using duplicate `ids`. It will cause your code to behave faulty especially when using javascript/jquery

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. It was really hard to create this border effect (make it the same length as the text + remain there on :focus) and I guess I didn't do it the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem  : do not use duplicate ID's = do not use an id more than once on a page. So remove all the `#menuu` id's and style the classes instead.

The menu is on the same row with some widgets ( for eg. social icons, phone no etc. ) that's why it doesn't have enough space.

You can solve your problem in different ways ( not sure exactly which would apply best in your case ) using media queries for 992px ( where the problems start )

```
@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
    styles here
}
```

- changing the font-size of the menu items and/or the widget text
  `font-size`
- hide the widgets alltogether `display:none`
- change the widths of the colums to have 3 on one row or whatever you
        like, for eg:  `.elementor-166 .elementor-element.elementor-element-462f96df { width:33.33%}`
- make all columns 100% width, as it happens when you pass `768px` for
        eg `.elementor-column { width:100%!important;}`

Anyway, my guess is that you can solve this with `media queries` and different styles depending on the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for all the elaborated suggestions. I have never used those media queries, can they be applied to specific classes or id's?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp or here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thank you. I started playing around with that. It all looked good until I opened my laptop which also has the resolution of 1920 width. What can cause the difference, if on my PC screen the  @media (min-width: 1920px) attributes look fine?

Comment: min-width:1920px means that it's for screens from 1920px and above ( 1921,1922 etc ) . Also try adding `@media only screen and (min-width:1920px)` or `max-width`

Comment: No what I asked is if I styled the 1920 screen  when I worked with my PC screen, and then checked it on my laptop which also has the resolution of 1920px, it looked different.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image, there are some inline-styles being applied to the `elementor-element` and that is making the overlapping issue. But I think that's dynamic on page load after calculating the page width and you have nothing to do with this. But what you can do is by overriding this style.

[image]